# SQL - get highest value from a string fragment

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following data stored in a `nvarchar` column:

```
11290796
21290795
31290794
```

I need get the data with the highest `int` value of the last four chars, so the result should look like this:

`11290796`

Comment: MAX(CONVERT((SUBSTRING(myColumn, -4, 4)), SIGNED INTEGER)) AS greatestNum

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in `nvarchar` columns and if the last four digits are significant, why? Does it represent something that should be stored separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to define the column as int instead of varchar, you can get what is needed with right and cast

```
Declare @maxval  int =
( select 
max(cast ( right(col, 4) as int)) from TableA )
Select * from TableA where cast ( right(col, 4) as int) = @maxval
```

Comment: This doesn't return the whole string.

Comment: Nice, except the OP has the column as varchar and is asking a question based on keeping a varchar column

Comment: It perfectly fits my needs. Thanks! The schema cannot be modified at the moment otherwise we would have changed it to int of course :)